# Why does ECL can calculate factorial (1000)?

Tags: common-lisp, ecl

It is awesome that ECL can calculate fac(1000) ! How can ECL do it ?

```
 >(defun fac (n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1)))))
 >(disassemble #'fac)
 #(FAC N = - * #<bytecompiled-function FAC> SI:FSET)
 Name:           FAC                                                                 
    0    POP     REQ
    1    BIND    N
    3    NOMORE
    4    PUSHV   0
    6    PUSH    1
    8    CALLG   2,=
   11    JNIL    18
   13    QUOTE   1
   15    SET     VALUES(0),REG0
   16    JMP     35
   18    PUSHV   0
   20    PUSHV   0
   22    PUSH    1
   24    CALLG   2,-
   27    PUSH    VALUES(0)
   28    CALLG   1,FAC
   31    PUSH    VALUES(0)
   32    CALLG   2,*
   35    EXIT
```

I know few about ECL bytecode. It seems there is no tail recursive optimization. Can any expert explain it ?

Sincerely!

Comment: This is the byte code, but probably the interpreter can do the optimization? And 1000 level of stack is not really a problem - the interpreter implementation should take care of this case already (if it really does recursion for this case).

Comment: 1000 is indeed not a problem. `(defun fac (n) (reduce #'* (loop for i from 1 to n collect i)))`  even calculate (fac 30000) or more. Wonderful (E)CL, thanks!

Comment: If the interpreter really keeps a stack, it will be implemented as data structure to function like a stack so it can go arbitrarily many levels of stack (not sure about the internal implementation, but it may impose a limit, or the limit is the limit of the system).

Comment: I don't see any tail recursion in the function (`#'*` is in the tail position), so tail call optimisation isn't relevant.

Answer (score 3):

ECL's interpreter currently does not make tail call optimization. It could be easily implemented, but I do not have the time to do it: basically it amounts to adding one flag to the bytecodes compiler to signal tail calls. In any case, as pointed out here, the ECL interpreter uses a dynamically allocated stack, plus a C stack for interpreter recursion. This means you will get about 1000 C stack frames (small) and some consed lists to keep track of the environment. Currently it suffices, which is ok. On the C side, though, ECL does detect self tail calls and can optimize many of them, and in other cases GCC optimizes mutual tail calls (calls to other functions in tail position).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ECL, but what I see from the source code you compiled and then later in dis-assembly, the compiler did its work properly. The function is defined as a recursive call to itself. The same I see in the dis-assembly. Thus, the only problems that may arise during call to this function is a stack overflow and arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Overflow occurs using newlisp to calculate fac(30), so what i really want to know is how (E)CL can do it without overflow.

Comment: btw, does it print out all 2568 digits of the result?

Comment: @z_axis Automatic promotion from fixnum to bignum, as the reult overflows the size of a fixnum. Relatively simple, in principle (but getting bignum math to be fast can be a bit tricky).